# When will travis-ci support ghc 7.10?

Tags: haskell, travis-ci

I'd like to use travis-ci on my Haskell projects, but they require the latest version of GHC.

Comment: The title of the question and the body contradicts one other. Does travis enforce the use of GHC 7.10 or lack support for it?

Comment: Travis lacks support.  The "they" was referring to my projects, not travis.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using [multi-ghc-travis](https://github.com/hvr/multi-ghc-travis), you can also set up Travis-CI for ghc 7.10 (apart from other versions).